# Using the same InfoWindow for two AttributeInspectors

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I've got two editable feature layers in my application, and I'm trying to attach the appropriate attribute inspector depending on which feature layer my user is trying to edit.

I create the Attribute Inspectors for both feature layers when my application loads and then attach the appropriate attribute inspector to the map's InfoWindow when the user is trying to edit a feature layer.

All works well, until the user tries to edit another feature layer. When I try and attach a different attribute inspector to the infowindow, it just comes up blank.

Here's roughly what I'm doing:

```
 // AttributeEditor1 for FeatureLayer1 in Class1

    constructor: function(options) {
        this.options = lang.mixin(this.options, options);
        this.map = options.map;
        this.configureAttributeEditor1();
    },

    configureAttributeEditor1: function() {

        this.attributeEditor1 = new AttributeInspector({
            layerInfos: layerInfos
        }, domConstruct.create("div"));

        // here I add a Save and Delete button and various event handlers

        this.attributeEditor1.startup();

    },

    // I call this when I know that the user wants to edit FeatureLayer 1
    attachEditor1: function() {
          this.map.infoWindow.setContent(this.attributeEditor1.domNode);
          this.map.infoWindow.resize(350, 240);
    },

 // AttributeEditor2 for FeatureLayer2 in Class2    

    constructor: function(options) {
        this.options = lang.mixin(this.options, options);
        this.map = options.map;
        this.configureAttributeEditor2();
    },

    configureAttributeEditor2: function() {

        this.attributeEditor2 = new AttributeInspector({
            layerInfos: layerInfos
        }, domConstruct.create("div"));

        // here I add a Save and Delete button and various event handlers

        this.attributeEditor2.startup();

    },

    // I call this when I know that the user wants to edit FeatureLayer 2
    attachEditor2: function() {
          this.map.infoWindow.setContent(this.attributeEditor2.domNode);
          this.map.infoWindow.resize(350, 240);
    },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean AttributeEditor1 works and AttributeEditor2 does not?

Comment: AttributeEditor1 works, until I swap the contents of the map's InfoWindow to AttributeEditor2. When I then try and add AttributeEditor1 again to the InfoWindow, it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the content of infoWindow using `map.infoWindow.setContent`, it destroys the previous content and then updated the new content. So basically your AttributeInspector1 will be destroyed when you updated the info window with AttributeInspector2.

You need not create multiple `AttributeInspector`, while working on multiple FeatureLayer. The `layerInfos` property is an array type, you could set upd multiple layers.

But, I guess you have different needs/actions to be taken when you switch between layers. The best thing you could do is to either create new AttributeInspector every time you switch, or just update the `layerInfos` and save and delete events. Make sure you remove the previous save and delete event handles.